# What is the mathematical model for simulating flanger?

Tags: flanger

Assuming the trigonometric functions use radians, a basic constant tone is represented by `s(t) = a * sin(2πf)`. How do I use `s(t)` to simulate flanging? I've tried `(s(t) + s(0.999t) / 2`, `(s(t) + s(t + 0.001sin(2πt))`, etc. with varying levels of closeness. I've gotten robot-like sounds. I've gotten dissonance. I've gotten waving dissonance. I understand how flanging is done with tapes. I just don't know how to digitally simulate it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A flanger is just a time-modulated, scaled version of the signal added back to the original signal.  Whether the signal is a single tone or not, the equation is `s_out( t) = s(t) + g*s( t-d(t) )`  where `g` is the gain applied to the added signal, and `d(t)` could, in principle be any periodic delay function, but is often just sinusoidal: `d(t) = c*[sin( 2*pi*m*t)+1]/2` where `c` the the maximum amount of delay, usually less than `20ms`, and `m` is the period of the modulation (in cycles per second) this could range from many tens of Hz down to much less than 1 Hz.  (there's a +1 to ensure that the amount of delay is always positive.)